# How to retrieve only UID from firebase and show in TableView

Tags: swift, firebase

Now it pulls in all the information from database. I want it to pull just information from users who have `storename` in database.

I can retrieve all but which one don't have `storename` it will show empty table in my application.

My Database from Firebase
[image: database]
My TableView
[image: my table]

my code how i can retrieve it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let refList = Database.database().reference().child("Users/Sellers")
        refList.observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                self.listProduct.removeAll()

                for lists in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
                    let productList = lists.childSnapshot(forPath: "user_info")
                    let userList = productList.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let listName = userList?["storename"]
//                    print("the Key value  \(lists.key) " )
                    print("key = \(self.shops)")
                    let list = StoreModel(name: listName as! String?)
                    self.shops.append(Shop(storename: listName as! String?, shop_id: lists.key ))
                    self.listProduct.append(list)
                }
                self.tableList.reloadData()
            }

        })

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return  UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listProduct.count

    }
```

I want it to pull just information from users who have `storename` in database and show in my tableview.

Comment: Is your question about how to query Firebase for only users that have a store name or are you having difficulty displaying data in your tableView? Or is your tableView displaying cells that are empty even though the dataSource contains storenames? Can you clarify the question? Can you include your tableView cell population code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
refList.observe(.value, with:{(snapshot) in
    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
        self.listProduct.removeAll()

        for lists in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
            let productList = lists.childSnapshot(forPath: "user_info")
            let userList = productList.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            if let listName = userList?["storename"] as? String {
                let list = StoreModel(name: listName)
                self.shops.append(Shop(storename: listName, shop_id: lists.key ))
                self.listProduct.append(list)

            }
        }
        self.tableList.reloadData()
    }

})
```

Comment: You save my day Thank a lot, change one thing 'FIRDataSnapshot' has been renamed to 'DataSnapshot'